# Enumerate next line in file object until n or EOF

Tags: python

In python <3.7, my code had a generator that ran through lines of a file object until a fixed value:

```py
def parse_header(file_object):
    for index, line in enumerate(next(file_object) for x in range(max_value)):
        # do stuff to index and line
```

In the event the EOF was reached first before the `max_value`, the StopIteration was previously allowable. However, with [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/#consequences-for-existing-code) the RuntimeError causes a problem, and I cannot figure out how to rewrite it to return instead.

Comment: can't you use `if index == max_value: break`

Comment: or `for index, line in zip(range(max_value), file_object):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, your code looks weird.

I would do

```
def parse_header(file_object):
    for index, line in enumerate(file_object):
        if index == max_value:
            break
        print(index, line)
```

or

```
def parse_header(file_object):
    for index, line in zip(range(max_value), file_object):
        print(index, line)
```

Both works in Python 3.7.3

After you use `parse_header(file_object)` you can still get next line with `next(file_object)`